# Remove references on extensions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, moq, nuget

I am using `Visual Studio .NET 2012` and `NuGet` to manage the References for my ASP.NET MVC 4 solution.

How can I remove a Reference created via `NuGet`?  I know I could just go and delete it via right-click, Remove.  However, this seems dangerous to me, as referenced packages may have brought in other dependencies of their own.

In my main project, I right-clicked `References->Manage NuGet Packages` and installed `Moq` (please see screenshot below)

[image: Manage NuGet Packages]

However, I was not able to reference `Moq` in my Tests.

I realized that the `Guestbook.Tests` Project that was created when I created my ASP.NET MVC 4 solution, and it has its own `References`.

So I added `Moq` here, but I would like to cleanup and remove `Moq` from my main `Guestbook` Project.

Could anyone please point me in the right direction of how to do this safely?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is to go to the `TOOLS` -> `Library Package Manager` -> `Package Manager Console` and enter the following:

`Uninstall-Package Moq`

You should always use the package manager rather than just deleting files so that it cleans everything up including anything you might miss.

Comment: Cool, thanks, I just tried that and it worked!  Also, good advice on using the package manager on cleanup.

Answer (score 4):

Using the same screen as the you show above, select installed packages, then find the MOQ reference you should then have the option to manage/uninstall.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, didn't see that other option of `Installed Packages`.  Viewing it on the `Online` menu, it only shows a green check of being installed.  I already uninstalled via @RyanGates answer, but +1 for another way to do it.

Comment: This method has the added advantage that when a package is installed in multiple projects, you can uninstall them all at once.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Package Manager Console with command: Uninstall-Package PackageId to remove it, or just delete package folder from 'packages' folder under solution folder. More information about Package Manager Console you can find here: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-manager-console-powershell-reference